# How to verify whether the table is sorted using C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the below table sorted & i want to verify the table is sorted in an order using C# selenium

first numeric values will be sorted and alphabets will be sorted.

## Display name

1 
2 
5
7
Abbot
Edfdsf
Fdsf

i need to to verify in c# selenium.

My Thoughts: is it easy way to convert each row value to ASCII number and compare with the next row ?

Please provide your suggestion?

Comment: i thought of applying ascii connvertion to each value and verifying it. Is that correct ?

Comment: Only thought is not welcome here..need to share what have tried with your thoughts...:)

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you store the display names in a `List`, copy the `List` and sort it, and then compare it to the original list.

```
List<String> displayNames = new List<string>();
// grab the cells that contain the display names you want to verify are sorted
IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> cells = Driver.FindElements(locator);
// loop through the cells and assign the display names into the ArrayList
foreach (IWebElement cell in cells)
{
    displayNames.Add(cell.Text);
}

// make a copy of the displayNames array
List<String> displayNamesSorted =  new List<string>(displayNames);
displayNamesSorted.Sort();
Console.WriteLine(displayNames.SequenceEqual(displayNamesSorted));
```

Answer (score 0):

Most elegant way:

```
var cells = WebDriver.FindElements(locator);
Assert.IsTrue(cells.OrderBy(c => c.Text).SequenceEqual(cells));
```